# downloading and Installing msi from sharefile

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, installation, silent, sharefile

I am trying to put together a powershell script to download firefox msi from sharefile and silently install.

I finally got the download part to work. However, installing does not. When I navigate to the folders where I downloaded firefox msi to (C:\, C:\users\public, and my desktop) I get the following errors:

This app can't run on your PC

This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify this is a valid windows installer package.

I downloaded the exe from mozilla site and msi from front motion.

The share the software is in is open to everyone on network.

I get same errors for both exe and msi.

This is my current script:

```
#Download and Run MSI package for Automated install
$uri = "https://sharefile.com/app/#/home/shared/foe0295b-0fbf-4ad9-ad73-fc18d26ba705/FirefoxInstaller.msi"
$out = "c:\FireFoxInstaller.msi"
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -OutFile $out
Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i $out /quiet /norestart /l c:\installlog.txt"
```

Comment: can you run the msi downloaded by your script manually? Also your link to sharefile ends in a 404

Comment: no, I tried installing manually and it gives the same error. The link brings up a 404 because I didn't include my company name.

Comment: does it work if you manually download the file? either the download doesnt work correctly or the file is just corrupted?

Comment: Yes, both the msi and exe work when if downloaded from the sites.

Comment: then maybe just try something else, like the .net web client

Comment: Then, by the looks of it, you didn't get the download part to work after all. I bet you're getting some kind of redirect page or login page or cookie check or something instead of the MSI. Is it the right size? Does Get-FileHash show the same hash for it as for a file downloaded by a browser?

Comment: Where would I find the hash? I looked under properties/digital signature but all it says is sha1. You have to be right about the download because I can pull them both from sharefile and install them.

Answer (score 4):

To grab the latest version of Firefox, try the following (replacing the Outfile to your own valid location);

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-msi-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-GB" -Outfile c:\temp\firefox.msi
```

To install, I use;

```
start /wait msiexec /i C:\temp\Firefox.msi /quiet
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had a similar issue, where I wanted to deploy HipChat to the whole company. The major difference is that I check if the software is already installed before downloading and trying to install it again, it's very simple and compatible with Windows 7 and 10:

```
$file = 'HipChat-4.29.5.1662-win32.msi'
$link = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/hipchat-ops/hipchat4/windows/$file"
$soft_name = 'Hipchat'

$find = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = `'$soft_name`'"

if ($find -eq $null) {

    $tmp = "$env:TEMP\$file"
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $client.DownloadFile($link, $tmp)

    msiexec /i $tmp /qn
    del $tmp
    echo "Tried installing $soft_name"

} else {
    echo "ERROR: $soft_name is already installed."
    echo $find
    exit 1
}

exit 0
```

Comment: It's useful. But for anyone curious / starting out. For wildcard filtering, i'd use `-Filter "Name LIKE \`'$soft_name\`%'"` *(Useful for when application name contains version numbers etc)*

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you have an MSI of your choice, but I justed used the MSI from [Frontmotion](http://www.frontmotion.com/news/firefox/releases/firefox-53-0-3/)

This worked when I did it, but let me know if it worked for you.

```
#Download and Run MSI package for Automated install
$uri = "http://hicap.frontmotion.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Firefox/Firefox-53.0.3/Firefox-53.0.3-en-US.msi"
$out = "c:\FireFoxInstaller.msi"

Function Download_MSI_FireFox_Installer{
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -OutFile $out
$msifile = Get-ChildItem -Path $out -File -Filter '*.ms*' 
write-host "FireFox MSI $msifile "
}

Function Install_FireFox{
$FileExists = Test-Path $msifile -IsValid
$DataStamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmmss
$logFile = '{0}-{1}.log' -f $msifile.fullname,$DataStamp
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $msifile.fullname)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)
If ($FileExists -eq $True)
{
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -passthru | wait-process
write-host "Finished msi "$msifile
}

Else {Write-Host "File doesn't exists"}
}
Download_MSI_FireFox_Installer
Install_FireFox
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the $msifile assignment needs to be moved outside the Download_MSI_FireFox_Installer function, otherwise, I get an error that the path is null in the InstallFireFox function.